# Is it good to pass minimal parameters?

Tags: java, design-patterns, coding-style

Assume I have an object Car, with five parameters, { numwheels, color, mileage, horsepower, maxSpeed }.
I have a method that needs 3 of these values.
Which of the 2 options is said to be best practice ? 
Is it better to pass enclosing object and reduce the number of parameters, OR just pass in bare-minimal data to a method (eg: numwheels and color will not be accessed in method 2) ?

1. Option 1 pass whole object:

   ```
   void compute(Car c, Person p) {
       return c.mileage + c.horsepower + c.maxSpeed + p.age;
   }
   ```
2. Option 2: pass in just the method values.

   ```
   void compute(int mileage, int horsepower, int maxSpeed, int age) {
       return mileage + horsepower + maxSpeed + age.;
   }
   ```

Note: assume for some reason, compute cannot be a part of Car class. Please answer with that assumption in mind.

Comment: It's probably taste that decides. Following convention always helps, so I'd say going with less arguments is more common, makes more sense, and most important is more flexible(Changing the fields in the `Car` class doesn't change the method signature)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's better to pass the enclosed object because any change in the number of parameters required in the computation wouldn't affect the method signature in future.

You can, in fact, accept an *interface* type, say, `Vehicle` instead. This allows the same method to compute data on `Bike`, `Jet` etc. later on.

```
public int compute(Vehicle veh) {
    return veh.computePerformance();
}
```

where `Car` implements the method as

```
public int computePerformance() {
    return mileage + horsepower + maxSpeed;
}
```

The idea is to write code that easily lends itself to extensibility.

Comment: It's better to pass the enclosed object because any change in the number of parameters required in the computation wouldn't affect the method signature in future. - That answers !

Answer (score 5):

I would suggest a third option: add a method "compute" to Car.

This is called "Tell, don't ask".

See http://martinfowler.com/bliki/TellDontAsk.html

Comment: lets say we `compute` needed another object called truck and could not be part  of car for some reason ?

Comment: @JavaDeveloper Maybe make an abstract superclass Vehicle and implement a non-abstract method `compute` inside it. Make Car, Truck, everything you need, inherit from that (or make it abstract if you wish to implement it later in subclasses).  Then all subclasses will automatically have `compute`. You can actually move the `mileage`, `horsepower`, and `maxSpeed` fields all to the superclass.

Comment: @Shashank lets assume that `compute` needs another class Person, who is not related in the class heirarchy. Point of the question is not to learn inheritance, its about `pass more params vs pass single object`

Comment: @JavaDeveloper If you absolutely must decide between those two options, then passing a single object is always better.

Comment: @Shashank that answers !

Comment: The last paragraph of the article starts with "But personally, I don't use tell-dont-ask." :)

Comment: @Michal I am very much aware of that. It is the same with any design rules; they are never cast in stone. And you know, there are very subtle things, like: I prefer to use string.isEmpty() over retrieving the length and comparing it to 0.

Answer (score 3):

I suggest second option.

Why?

**Assumption one**: Your compute method is used by some other class to compute mileage say 'class Owner'

**Assumption two**:Assume that tomorrow your compute method needs one more attribute from class Car to compute the mile age.

If you go by option one: then you will have to introduce one more parameter in method compute which would lead to compilation issues in other classes which are calling your method. In this case 'class Owner'.

If you go by option two: You have the **flexibility to update your compute method implementation without affecting any other class which is using this method**.